# Python: web scrape xhr with requests

Tags: javascript, python, xmlhttprequest, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some information from a javascript heavy web site. Usually I can piece some way  to read a page from the xhr header information using chrome's inspector or firebug, but nothing I've tried so far works.

I could use selenium or the like, but I'd rather use requests, if possible.

Here's a sample url:
https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&cntry_code=in&tracknumbers=770562143139 I'm trying to get the delivery status and related info.

I'm hoping some combination of gets or posts with appropriate parameters will work. I realize there are many similar questions here, such as [Scrape ajax web page with python and/or scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587855/scrape-ajax-web-page-with-python-and-or-scrapy) or [How to call ajax in a webpage from python script without browser emulation or headless brawser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515642/how-to-call-ajax-in-a-webpage-from-python-script-without-browser-emulation-or-he)

Comment: If this is about tracking, you could just use FedEx API that can provide info on delivery info among other things.

Comment: @SaikiranYerram It's just for tracking deliveries to me.  I thought I needed to be a business and get credentials to use the API.  I'll take another look. In any event, I'm still interested in figuring how to scrape the page.

Comment: @SaikiranYerram I can't figure out how to use the API without a key and password and they want an extensive application for that. Also, their sample code requires some libraries and they don't offer a python library, although https://pythonhosted.org/fedex/ looks promising.

Comment: You can use `requests` library to make the api call. I would imagine they want to just get profile of the developer or company, which makes sense. Also, Python isn't a right tool for running JS scripts. Have you looked at PhantomJS.org

Comment: @SaikiranYerram I've used phantomJS with selenium.  I'd like something much lighter than that, if possible. It usually is possible to find the right url and cookie combination to get a javascript generated page. It certainly makes sense for FedEx to know its developers. The problem for an individual is getting properly signed up.